# What is the unit used for duration AnjLab SQL profiler

Tags: sql, profiler

I am using AnjLab SQL profiler. Does anyone have about units used for CPU and duration columns ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just got the reply from AnjLab Team, for CPU it is in miliseconds and for Duration, it is in microseconds.